# MvvmCross DownloadCache plugin breaks bindings in custom controls on Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've wanted to use DownloadCache plugin in my MvvmCross project, but when I've added this package from nugget it broken bindings in custom controls on Android.
I'm using MvvmCross v.3.1.1
I have tried:

1. Updating MvvmCross and all plugins to v.3.2.2, but this did't helped.
2. Using target bindings instead of custom control properties, this has helped me, but this solution is not satisfying, because I have lots of custom controls where bindings are broken.

Also I can see an error in output saying:

> MvxBind:Warning: 41,01 Failed to create target binding for binding ControlProperty for ViewModelProperty

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you edit the question to provide a bit more info on The code around this binding that is failing - and why you think the failure is linked to the cache.

Comment: @Stuart Hi, I think failure is linked to the cache because when I'm deleting package of DownloadCache plugin bindings start working